# Why does my torrent stop uploading when download completes?

Tags: bittorrent

The title says it all: Why does my torrent stop uploading when download completes?

It has nothing to do with ports because it starts uploading when I'm downloading.

I use BitComet.

Comment: torrent clients often can be configured to cease uploading once some condition is reached -- the download completes, a certain up/down ratio is reached, etc.  check your configuration.  if it isn't that, perhaps your ports aren't opened, so new incoming connections are blocked.  this would not prevent uploads while downloading, as your download creates new outgoing connections that can be used for uploading.

Answer (score 2):

Is it **exactly** when you finish downloading all the time? If it's not you may not be noticing the share ratio. Bitcomet has a feature where it can stop uploading after you reach a certain share ratio. You can check this under **Options -> Preferences -> Task**:

[image]

The default is "no limit".

Comment: I know that one, it's uploading sometimes, but not all the time. Can it be that there is nobody out there who needs the file?

Comment: That's a possibility, but if you're seeding right until the file's done, that's doubtful. It may very well be a port forwarding issue as ~quack explained.